# Dereference a Member of struct Struct_type with (*variable).member vs *variable.member

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Given:

```
typedef struct Person_struct { char name[10]; int age; } Person;
Person bob;

void makePerson(Person *human) { 
   strcpy((*human).name, "Bob Bee");
   (*human).age = 36;
}
```

Dereferencing then takes the general form:

```
(*variable).member //variable could be bob, member could be age
```

I know that the member access operator `.` has precedence over `*` so we use parenthesis to dereference the variable first. I don't really understand why this is necessary.

It actually seems more intuitive that `*variable.member` would first operate on the member access operator to get the pointer-to-struct_type and then `.member` would add `sizeof(member)` to get the location to be deferenced.

But the proper form `(*variable).member` is very nonintuitive. It is not clear what 'value' is actually being returned by `(*variable)` nor is it clear how the member will be accessed from whatever is returned.

My question is:

What is going on in memory when `(*variable).member` is used as opposed to `*variable.member`?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55030392/return-variable-struct-members) but it did not answer my question.

Comment: Why don't you use `->`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use `*variable.member` is because the variable in this case is a pointer, not a structure, and you can't use the member access operator on a pointer. We have a separate operator `->` for doing member access on the dereferenced pointer:

```
strcpy(human->name, "Bob Bee");
```

Comment: His question is "What is going on in memory ..." :)

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the member access operator `.` has precedence over `*` so we use parenthesis to dereference the variable first. I don't really understand why this is necessary.

You just said it: the member access operator `.` has precedence over te dereference operator `*`. If you are asking *why `.` has precedence*, that's just a design choice.

> the proper form (*variable).member is very nonintuitive

I'd say it's annoying rather than nonintuitive. In fact, this is such a common operation that there's an operator for it. You can use the `->` operator to access fields of a struct when you have a pointer to it.

```
human->age = 36
// same as
(*human).age = 36
```

> What is going on in memory when `(*variable).member` is used as opposed to `*variable.member`?

Doing `(*variable).member` is the same as saying "take the address inside `variable` and dereference it, then take the `member` field of the struct you just obtained".

Doing `*variable.member` is the same as saying "take the address inside the `member` field of the struct `variable`, then dereference it". If `variable` is a pointer, that's of course just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

It much depends on how your compiler handles the *meaning* of the symbol.

For example, in C++, the statement `(*variable).member`, `(*variable)` can be interpreted as a `reference` to the actual object.

```cpp
Person bob;
Person* ptr = &bob;

Person& ref = *ptr;
```

Reference can be used as the actual object in its context.

But, in the perspective of a compiler, `(*variable)` has meaning only at the `immediate step` in the compiling process.

At the final step (binary), `(*variable)` loses its meaning.

The only thing left is `(*variable).member` be interpreted as `variable->member`. That means, take the pointer `variable`, dereference it using type `Person`, get the actual attribute from the prototype of `Person` struct.

Example:

```c
struct Person {
    char* name;
    int age;
};
Person bob;
printf("%d\n", bob.age);
```

A possible binary code can be

```
1. advance stack pointer about `sizeof(Person) = 16 bytes` (determined at compile time for 64bit machine). Top of the stack now contains the value of object bob
2. put the last 8 bytes on top of the stack into `printf` function. (You are gonna learnt more about this later)
```

Hope it helps